# why Selenium Python cannot see the web page as i do in the browser

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, checkbox, automated-tests

When I do `driver.page_source`

The HTML result in the code is not what I see in the browser and I cannot even find my element on it!

[image]

[Text File](https://file.io/WjIxbIy4QRcF)

my code:

```
> from selenium import webdriver
> from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
> from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
> from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
> from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
> import time
> 
> 
> webdriver_path = r'C:*******\chromedriver.exe'  # Replace with the actual path
> chrome_options = Options()
> 
> chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
> 
> chrome_options.add_argument(f'--webdriver-path={webdriver_path}')
> 
> driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
> 
> 
> 
> try:
> Open the URL
> url = "https://XXXXX:xxxxx/ossfacewebsite/index.html#Access/Access_RANWizard"
> driver.get(url)
> time.sleep(5)
> driver.execute_script
> WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(lambda driver: driver.execute_script("return document.readyState") == "complete")
> driver.execute_script
> #code stock in below line because element does not exist in the page source
> WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//tbody/tr/td/div[contains(@class, 'eui_checkbox')]")))
> 
> a = driver.page_source
> print (a)
> 
> checkbox_xpath = "//tbody/tr/td/div[contains(@class, 'eui_checkbox')]"
> checkbox = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, checkbox_xpath)
> driver.execute_script("arguments[0].classList.add('checked')", checkbox)
> 
> Click on Next
> next_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(@class, 'eui-btn-content') and text()='Next']")
> next_button.click()
> WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(@class, 'eui-btn-content') and text()='Finish']")))
> 
> time.sleep(100)
> 
> 
> finally:
> driver.quit()
```

I want to click on the check box but the check box that I see in the browser does not exist in the page source when I run my Python code but it is funny that it exists on the browser that pops up by the code! Also, it seems HUAWEI is using React for the development of MAE/U2020.

Comment: probably because of cookies and the fact that the website can check if you're a Python agent/bot or a real person